# Linux System Wakeup on GPIO Interrupt

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, gpio, sysfs

I'm working with a Linux system that configures a GPIO in user space. That is, there is no device tree entry for that GPIO. I exports the GPIO in sysfs and I want to know if an interrupt on that pin will wake up the system. So the way I declare the pin is I do

```sh
echo $PIN_NUM > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

This creates a virtual file at */sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN_NUM*

I then proceed to configure this as a falling edge-sensitive interrupt by doing the following

```sh
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN_NUM/direction
echo "falling" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN_NUM/edge
```

According to this [kernel.org article](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt), the fact that */sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN_NUM/edge* virtual file exists means the pin supports being an interrupt-generating input. Does this by definition mean my system will wakeup from sleep on that GPIO?  If not, how do I know if a particular GPIO interrupt is capable of waking up the system?

Comment: Forget about this legacy way. Simple start using `libgpiod` instead. Waking up is a property orthogonal to the manipulations with GPIO. And I don't see any mention of wake capability in GPIO library. It means it's solely depends on the GPIO driver in question. Some of them enable pins to be wake sources by default (all of them), some do filtering, some expect DT or ACPI hint on it. On respectively new kernels you may try `grep -H enabled /sys/kernel/irq/*/wakeup`.

Comment: Specify what hardware you are using.  Sleep and wake-up capabilities are typically handled by a power-management subsystem.